# Class shows up in auto complete but can't be imported -IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-management

The Services project uses a class in DataLayer. I have added the dependency to Services POM. When trying to import UserRepository class from DataLayer, IntelliJ autocomplete shows the class but when I press enter,it says "Can not resolve symbol DataLayer".

I checked the local maven repository and can see the Jar file in the proper place.

Tried invalidating cache which did not work.

Reimporting dependencies did not work either.

Here are the POM files of both the projects as well as screenshots from intelliJ

Services - pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.schoolgallery</groupId>
<artifactId>Services</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Services</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.schoolgallery</groupId>
        <artifactId>DataLayer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

DataLayer - pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.schoolgallery</groupId>
<artifactId>DataLayer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DataLayer</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Error appears as :

[image]

**EDIT**

The project has an MVC architecture with separate modules for API,Services and DataLayer.

Please find the project structures for services and datalayer.

[image: Services]

[image: DataLayer]

[image]

Comment: could you show your project structure and the place where `LoginService` is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the parent POM dependency to the Child projects did the trick !!

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.schoolgallery</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Remember to change the spring boot starter parent if you have a custom parent POM , because having two parent tags will throw an error.

This is described nicely [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent)